# How to quickly export data from R to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, bigdata

The standard RODBC package's `sqlSave` function even as a single `INSERT` statement (parameter `fast = TRUE`) is terribly slow for large amounts of data due to non-minimal loading. How would I write data to my SQL server with minimal logging so it writes much more quickly?

Currently trying:

```
toSQL = data.frame(...);
sqlSave(channel,toSQL,tablename="Table1",rownames=FALSE,colnames=FALSE,safer=FALSE,fast=TRUE);
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

By writing the data to a CSV locally and then using a `BULK INSERT` (not readily available as a prebuilt function akin to `sqlSave`), the data can be written to the MS SQL Server very quickly.

```
toSQL = data.frame(...);
write.table(toSQL,"C:\\export\\filename.txt",quote=FALSE,sep=",",row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE,append=FALSE);
    sqlQuery(channel,"BULK
                INSERT Yada.dbo.yada
                FROM '\\\\<server-that-SQL-server-can-see>\\export\\filename.txt'
                WITH
                (
                FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
                ROWTERMINATOR = '\\n'
                )");
```

SQL Server must have permission to access the network folder holding the CSV file, or else this process will not work. While it takes some setup with various permissions (the network folder and `BULK ADMIN` privileges, the reward in speed is infinitely more valuable).

Comment: Just a question to follow on the solution provided by @Jpd527. Am I right in thinking filename.txt should be filename.csv? Just that you mentioned that it would help to save the data as csv but I don't seem to see CSV in your solution.

Comment: You would think so, but the `BULK INSERT` command is picky and wants a `.txt`. The actual contents of the file are identical to a CSV; the only difference is a semantic file ending to make SQL happy.

Comment: thanks @jpd527, this is wonderful. I was having similar scenario and same doubt about .csv file. Thanks a tone.

Comment: What about column names? How does SQL know its names as long as `col.names=FALSE`?

Comment: @cineS. BULK INSERT needs a pre-existing table, so the SQL table would already have the column names. You would have to make sure the order of the columns was the same in the SQL table and the "txt" file.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree that `BULK INSERT` is the right option for any data which are *non-tiny*.
However in case you need to add 2-3 lines of e.g. debug message it `BULK INSERT` seems to be an overkill.

The answer to your question would be a `DBI::dbWriteTable()` function. Example below (I am connecting my R code to `AWS RDS` instance of `MS SQL Express`):

```
library(DBI)
library(RJDBC)
library(tidyverse)

# Specify where you driver lives
drv <- JDBC(
  "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
  "c:/R/SQL/sqljdbc42.jar") 

# Connect to AWS RDS instance
conn <- drv %>%
  dbConnect(
    host = "jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.ccgqenhjdi18.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com",
    user = "xxx",
    password = "********",
    port = 1433,
    dbname= "qlik")

if(0) { # check what the conn object has access to
  queryResults <- conn %>%
    dbGetQuery("select * from information_schema.tables")
}

# Create test data
example_data <- data.frame(animal=c("dog", "cat", "sea cucumber", "sea urchin"),
                           feel=c("furry", "furry", "squishy", "spiny"),
                           weight=c(45, 8, 1.1, 0.8))
# Works in 20ms in my case
system.time(
  conn %>% dbWriteTable(
    "qlik.export.test",
    example_data
  )
)

# Let us see if we see the exported results
conn %>% dbGetQuery("select * FROM qlik.export.test")

# Let's clean the mess and force-close connection at the end of the process
conn %>% dbDisconnect()
```

It works pretty fast for small amount of data transferred and seems rather elegant if you want `data.frame` -> `SQL table` solution.

Enjoy!

Comment: RJDBC is notoriously slower and much more difficult to setup than RODBC. The standard sqlSave returns in a similarly negligible number of miliseconds for only a few lines.