# What is the fastest way to load huge .Rdata files (R dataframes) into SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, r, dataframe, rodbc, bigdata

I am currently using library(RODBC) via:

```
dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=xxxxxx;database=yyyy;trusted_connection=true')
sqlSave(dbhandle, R_table ,tablename = "SQL_table" )
```

The problem with this one is, it takes about 5 hours to load 10 Million rows into SQL Server.

Also it breaks while loading sometimes. So, I break the .Rdata into smaller chunks and sequentially load it into SQL Server.

Is there any quicker way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would export my data in CSV format and use `BULK INSERT`. If you **really** want (or have) to use sqlSave, then, the only options that come to my mind are:

1. be sure to set `fast=TRUE` in sqlSave
2. set auto commit off before running sqlSave: `odbcSetAutoCommit(dbhandle, autoCommit = FALSE)` and commit after sqlSave `odbcEndTran(dbhandle, commit = TRUE)`

But, in my opinion, the real solution is BULK INSERT.

Comment: Thanks @mauro. Yes, I was looking for R specific solution. I would try what you have suggested, but do you think is there a way to run the export in parallel and distribute the processes to cores anyhow ? or is there any Rx package that could help ?

Comment: @SVK don't think you can easily parallelise sqlSave(). Re-BULK INSERT you can run it from RODBC: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37688685/how-can-we-bulk-insert-data-in-sqlserver-without-creating-a-text-file-from-rodbc

Comment: your answer was helpful could you share syntax to use RODBC for BULK INSERT.

Comment: @SVK something like `sqlQuery(connectionHandle, 'BULK INSERT <my.target.table> FROM <myfile> WITH...')`? I don't have a SQL Server instance to test but I use something like this with an ther databases...