# R: Insert csv-file into database using RJDBC

Tags: r, insert, bulkinsert, rjdbc

As **RJDBC** is the only package I have been able to make work on Ubuntu, I am trying to use it to **INSERT** a **CSV-file** into a database.

I can make the following work:

```
# Connecting to database
library(RJDBC)
drv <- JDBC('com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver', 'drivers/sqljdbc42.jar', identifier.quote="'")
connection_string <- "jdbc:sqlserver://blablaserver;databaseName=testdatabase"
ch <- dbConnect(drv, connection_string, "username", "password")

# Inserting a row
dbSendQuery(ch, "INSERT INTO cpr_esben.CPR000_Startrecord (SORTFELT_10,OPGAVENR,PRODDTO,PRODDTOFORRIG,opretdato) VALUES ('TEST', 123, '2012-01-01', '2012-01-01', '2012-01-01')")
```

The insert works. Next I try to make an **INSERT** of a CSV-file with the same data, that is separated by the default "tab" and I am working on windows.

```
# Creating csv
df <- data.frame(matrix(c('TEST', 123, '2012-01-01', '2012-01-01', '2012-01-01'), nrow = 1), stringsAsFactors = F)
colnames(df) <- c("SORTFELT_10","OPGAVENR","PRODDTO","PRODDTOFORRIG","opretdato")
class(df$SORTFELT_10) <- "character"
class(df$OPGAVENR) <- "character"
class(df$PRODDTO) <- "character"
class(df$PRODDTOFORRIG) <- "character"
class(df$opretdato) <- "character"
write.table(df, file = "test.csv", col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)

# Inserting CSV to database
dbSendQuery(ch, "INSERT cpr_esben.CPR000_Startrecord FROM 'test.csv'")

Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for INSERT cpr_esben.CPR000_Startrecord FROM 'test.csv' (Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.)
```

Do you have any suggestions to what I am doing wrong, when trying to insert the csv-file? I do not get the **Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'** error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you create a statement from your data? Something like:

```
# Data from your example
df <- data.frame(matrix(c('TEST', 123, '2012-01-01', '2012-01-01', '2012-01-01'), nrow = 1), stringsAsFactors = F)
colnames(df) <- c("SORTFELT_10","OPGAVENR","PRODDTO","PRODDTOFORRIG","opretdato")
class(df$SORTFELT_10) <- "character"
class(df$OPGAVENR) <- "character"
class(df$PRODDTO) <- "character"
class(df$PRODDTOFORRIG) <- "character"
class(df$opretdato) <- "character"

# Formatting rows to insert into SQL statement
rows <- apply(df, 1, function(x){paste0('"', x, '"', collapse = ', ')})
rows <- paste0('(', rows, ')')

# SQL statement
statement <- paste0(
  "INSERT INTO cpr_esben.CPR000_Startrecord (", 
  paste0(colnames(df), collapse = ', '), 
  ')',
  ' VALUES ',
  paste0(rows, collapse = ', ')
)

dbSendQuery(ch, statement)
```

This should work for any number of rows in your df

Comment: This is a very ugly solution if you have large dataframes, but I did end up doing something similar. I ended up writing the CSV-file to a file, and then used BCP to upload the data.

Comment: If no better solutions show up, then I will just give you the solution, as it does do the trick.

Comment: Yes, this is ugly, but I believe this is the only way to go using the `dbSendQuery` function. `dbWriteTable` does something similar under the hood, but you don't see the ugly statement it generates xD

Answer (score 0):

RJDBC is built on DBI, which has many useful functions to do tasks like this. What you want is `dbWriteTable`. Syntax would be:

```
dbWriteTable(ch, 'cpr_esben.CPR000_Startrecord', df, append = TRUE)
```

and would replace your write.table line.

I am not that familiar with RJDBC specifically, but I think the issue with your sendQuery is that you are referencing `test.csv` inside your SQL statement, which does not locate the file that you created with `write.table` as the scope of that SQL statement is not in your working directory.

Comment: My issue when using the "write table" approach is that I need permission to create a new table in the database (even if I choose "append=TRUE"). The reason why I chose to refer to my csv-file in the SQL-query, was that I was inspired by this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19190744/how-to-quickly-export-data-from-r-to-sql-server

Comment: If you don't have write access nothing will work, what permissions do you have exactly ?

Comment: Agreed with Moody. If you want to replicate the example you linked, you also need to reflect the full path structure that they use.

Comment: I have write access, but I do not have access to create new tables.

Comment: How is `DBI::dbWriteTable(..., append=TRUE)` creating a new table? Typically, `create=TRUE,append=TRUE` is directly contradicting and will error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried loading the file directly to the database as below.

```
library(RJDBC)
drv <- JDBC("connections")      
conn <- dbConnect(drv,"...")

query = "LOAD DATA INFILE 'test.csv' INTO TABLE test"
dbSendUpdate(conn, query)
```

You can also try to include other statements in the end like delimiter for column like `"|"` for .txt file and `","` for csv file.