# How can i do a query with SQLsave in R?

Tags: sql, r, rstudio, rodbc

I have a question about SqlSave ,

I Know that sqlsave Writes a Data Frame to a Table in an ODBC Database , but i would like to write an insert query.

How can i do that with Sqlsave ,can u give me an example ?

Thank you

Comment: sqlSave cannot work with query... If you already have your query then why don't you use sqlQuery function?

Comment: @vrajs5 this is the point ,sqlQuery works but it does not scale very well, i have to insert a lot of values but it insert only the first row, to resolve that i did a loop still it's not working as i expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the structure of your `my_df data.frame` is equal to the table `my_table` in a data base (same column names and formats) the next query will insert new data to it:

```
con <- odbcConnect("my_dsn", uid = "my_uid", pwd = "my_pwd")

sqlSave(con, my_newdf, tablename = "my_table", 
        append = TRUE, rownames = FALSE, colnames = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question already answered => [How to insert a dataframe into a SQL Server table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334840/how-to-insert-a-dataframe-into-a-sql-server-table)

Read RODBC manual http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/index.html