# How to insert a single row R data.frame into a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, rodbc

I'm struggling to append a new row of data into an existing SQL Server database.

These:

```
sqlQuery(con, paste("INSERT INTO df1 SELECT * FROM df2"))

sqlQuery(con, paste("INSERT INTO df1 SELECT * FROM ", df2))

sqlQuery(con, paste("INSERT INTO df1 SELECT * FROM ", sqldf("SELECT * FROM df2")))
```

All produce an error:

> [1] "42S02 -1305 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot find the input table or query 'col_1_val'.  Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly."
>
> [2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'INSERT INTO df1 SELECT * FROM  col_1_val'"

`col_1_val` is the first column value in `df2`

Going the `sqlSave` route:

```
sqlSave(con, df2, tablename = "df1", append = TRUE, rownames = FALSE, colnames = FALSE)
```

throws a memory allocation error:

> Error in odbcUpdate(channel, query, mydata, coldata[m, ], test = test, : 'Calloc' could not allocate memory (1073741824 of 1 bytes)

Comment: Are the tables df1 and df2 existing?

Comment: Well, at least you need an additional ) at the end of each.

Comment: df1 = existing SQL Server database and df2 = existing R data.frame

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert a dataframe into a SQL Server table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334840/how-to-insert-a-dataframe-into-a-sql-server-table)

Comment: iamdave, I saw that answer before I posted this, do I just have to list all values in df1 and df2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the assumption that the names and the order of columns in `df1` and `df2` are identical, this should work:

```
query <- 
  paste0("INSERT INTO df1 ",
         "(", paste0(names(df2), collapse = ", "), ") ",
         "VALUES (",
         paste0(rep("?", length(df2)), collapse = ", "), ")")

library(RODBCext)

sqlExecute(con, 
           query,
           data = df2)
```

The query that is written looks like this, when using `mtcars` as `df1`.

```
"INSERT INTO df1 (mpg, cyl, disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, vs, am, gear, carb) VALUES ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?"
```

This permits you to generate the statement that adds all of column names to the query without having to manually declare them.  Using `sqlExecute` invokes a parameterized query. The question marks are then bound to your data and then executed as part of the statement.

Comment: I can't get any version of this to work, why would I want to rep the SQL statement for every column?

Comment: My apologies, I misplaced a parenthesis.  `query` should be a length one character vector.  I've fixed it in the answer.

Comment: 42000 -3502 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. [RODBCext] Error: SQLExecute failed...  

Not enough storage on the server? Don't have write access?

Comment: `ODBC Microsoft Access Driver` that's a curious part of the error that I didn't catch before.  I've never used that driver with SQL Server.  How are you forming your connection?

Comment: RODBC::odbcConnectAccess(), I need to connect directly to the server, don't I? My frontend is via Access, backend is a SQL database

Comment: If you can connect directly to SQL Server, I would strongly recommend it.

Comment: Was never able to write directly to the SQL server but your code worked a charm for an Access table I was using for an Excel import, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

TRY

```
INSERT INTO table1 ( column1 )
SELECT  col1
FROM    table2
```

if you want columns from table 2

```
INSERT INTO table1 ( column1, column2, someInt, someVarChar )
SELECT  table2.column1, table2.column2, 8, 'some string etc.'
FROM    table2
```

Comment: But I want all columns from table2.

Comment: what about now @ SCDCE